# Tooth enamel regeneration

Tags: dentistry, reference-request

I have been listening to a poscast at Naked Scientists ([Haylor, 2018](https://www.thenakedscientists.com/podcasts/short/regenerating-tooth-enamel)) where the host was talking to researcher, Alvaro Mata, about the possibility of regerating tooth enamel by painting a substance onto decayed teeth.

Does anyone know of Mata's research paper and if so, what are the details?

### References

Haylor, K. (2018). Regenerating tooth enamel, *The Naked Scientists Podcasts & Science Radio Shows.*
Available at: https://www.thenakedscientists.com/podcasts/short/regenerating-tooth-enamel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mata is onto that issue for quite some time:

> [Zhan Huang  Timothy D Sargeant  James F Hulvat  Alvaro Mata  Pablo Bringas Jr  Chung‐Yan Koh Samuel I Stupp  Malcolm L Snead: "Bioactive Nanofibers Instruct Cells to Proliferate and Differentiate During Enamel Regeneration", JBMR, Volume23, Issue12, December 2008, Pages 1995-2006](https://doi.org/10.1359/jbmr.080705)

His latest publication has a less obvious on-topic title:

> [Sherif Elsharkawy, Maisoon Al-Jawad, Maria F. Pantano, Esther Tejeda-Montes, Khushbu Mehta, Hasan Jamal, Shweta Agarwal, Kseniya Shuturminska, Alistair Rice, Nadezda V. Tarakina, Rory M. Wilson, Andy J. Bushby, Matilde Alonso, Jose C. Rodriguez-Cabello, Ettore Barbieri, Armando del Río Hernández, Molly M. Stevens, Nicola M. Pugno, Paul Anderson & Alvaro Mata: "Protein disorder–order interplay to guide the growth of hierarchical mineralized structures", Nature Communicationsvolume 9, Article number: 2145 (2018)](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-04319-0)
> A major goal in materials science is to develop bioinspired functional materials based on the precise control of molecular building blocks across length scales. Here we report a protein-mediated mineralization process that takes advantage of disorder–order interplay using elastin-like recombinamers to program organic–inorganic interactions into hierarchically ordered mineralized structures. The materials comprise elongated apatite nanocrystals that are aligned and organized into microscopic prisms, which grow together into spherulite-like structures hundreds of micrometers in diameter that come together to fill macroscopic areas. The structures can be grown over large uneven surfaces and native tissues as acid-resistant membranes or coatings with tuneable hierarchy, stiffness, and hardness. Our study represents a potential strategy for complex materials design that may open opportunities for hard tissue repair and provide insights into the role of molecular disorder in human physiology and pathology.

A more accessible press release is found at

> [Scientists develop material that could regenerate dental enamel](https://www.qmul.ac.uk/media/news/2018/se/scientists-develop-material-that-could-regenerate-dental-enamel-.html)
> Researchers at Queen Mary University of London have developed a new way to grow mineralised materials which could regenerate hard tissues such as dental enamel and bone.

While incredibly promising we might want to hold out horse for a little bit longer:

> The research team is now looking into developing applications for this material.
>
> “The technology could benefit many people and [commercialization] is the ultimate goal of our work,” says Alvaro Mata, who led the research group.[…]
> “It is certainly a possibility,” Mata elaborates. “The kinds of regenerative challenges that we are talking about will require collaboration between disciplines and integration of different technologies. We are very keen to collaborate with different people to make things happen.”[…]
> The UK seems to be a hotspot for research into tooth regeneration. At King’s College London, researchers performed experiments in mice that showed that an Alzheimer’s drug stimulated natural repair processes in stem cells found inside teeth to fill cavities.
>
> On the industrial side of things, the Swiss company Credentis is developing protein molecules that help apatite crystals form new enamel and using its technology in a range of oral care products, from toothpaste and mouthwash to chewing gum. The British company BioMin Technologies uses glass-ceramic biomaterials that release phosphate molecules in response to acidic conditions in order to repair dental enamel.
>
> With the combined efforts in biotech and academia, it’s exciting to think we may one day be able to regenerate our enamel and coax our teeth into filling their own cavities. Who knows, these research efforts may help us avoid another uncomfortable visit to the dentist.
> <sub>[British Researchers Regenerate Tooth Enamel With Biopolymers](https://labiotech.eu/dental-enamel-biopolymers/)</sub>

Comment: Looking at the press release, it seems you have found the originating article. ([Elsharkawy, et al. 2018](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41467-018-04319-0)).

Answer (score 1):

I was going to post a possible answer when @LangLangC posted some interesting articles.

Interestingly there is another atricle:

> [Shuturminska, K., Tarakina, N. V., Azevedo, H. S., Bushby, A. J., Mata, A., Anderson, P., & Al-Jawad, M. (2017). Elastin-Like Protein, with Statherin Derived Peptide, Controls Fluorapatite Formation and Morphology. *Frontiers in physiology*, 8, 368.](https://doi.org/10.3389/fphys.2017.00368)
>   The process of enamel biomineralization is multi-step, complex and mediated by organic molecules. The lack of cells in mature enamel leaves it unable to regenerate and hence novel ways of growing enamel-like structures are currently being investigated. Recently, elastin-like protein (ELP) with the analog *N*-terminal sequence of statherin (STNA<sub>15</sub>-ELP) has been used to regenerate mineralized tissue. Here, the STNA<sub>15</sub>-ELP has been mineralized in constrained and unconstrained conditions in a fluoridated solution. We demonstrate that the control of STNA<sub>15</sub>-ELP delivery to the mineralizing solution can form layered ordered fluorapatite mineral, via a brushite precursor. We propose that the use of a constrained STNA<sub>15</sub>-ELP system can lead to the development of novel, bioinspired enamel therapeutics.

Comment: I start to really like this guy. Wonder why he is so modest and does not appear as lead author in most of the papers?

Comment: Interesting articles you both posted above, have either of you come across any further research or developments on this since?